Creating multiple new rows with certain columns in R
I have a dataset that includes multiple biological samples collected for each patient, but within the data output all samples are in the same row. I would like to manipulate the data so that each sample is in its own row.
The dataframe currently looks like the following: (this is a simplified fake version of the data)
Patient_ID   Patient_name   Sample_1_ID   Sample_1_value1  Sample_1_value2   Sample_2_ID   Sample_2_value1   Sample_2_value2  Sample_3_ID   Sample_3_value1   Sample_3_value2
AB100         AB             CSF            1.0             2.0               CSF            2.0               3.0             CSF              2.0             4.0
JM200         JM             CSF            2.0             3.0               CSF            4.0               5.0             CSF              3.0             4.0

I would like the final dataframe to look like:
Patient_ID   Patient_name   Sample_ID   Sample_value1  Sample_value2
AB100          AB             CSF            1.0             2.0
AB100          AB             CSF            2.0             3.0
AB100          AB             CSF            2.0             4.0
JM200          JM             CSF            2.0             3.0
JM200          JM             CSF            4.0             5.0
JM200          JM             CSF            3.0             4.0

I tried to do this using dplyr's add_row() function, but I can't figure out how to duplicate the patient identifier rows while moving down just the sample data.
Thank you in advance.

This concept is called converting data into "long form"
Below is the R syntax to accomplish this:
We will use tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

long_df <- df %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -c(Patient_ID, Patient_name), 
        names_to = c(".value", "set"), 
        names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)"
    )


cols = -c(Patient_ID, Patient_name): This specifies the columns to
transform. The - indicates that all columns except Patient_ID and
Patient_name should be transformed.
names_to = c(".value", "set"):
This tells the function how to create new column names. .value
indicates that part of the original column name should be used as the
new column name (i.e., ID, value1, value2).
names_pattern = "(.\*)_(.\*)": This regular expression captures the patterns in the
column names. The first (.\*) captures the prefix (e.g., Sample_1) and
the second (.\*) captures the suffix (ID, value1, value2), which
corresponds to the new column names.


Thank you! I didn't realize when pivoting into the long form you could leave/repeat the ID columns
